# Clean up my RoR development environment

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, uninstallation, rvm

I started RoR development a few months ago, and being new to Mac...

Time flies and now I have a lot different ruby versions, rails versions and gems versions located everywhere......And currently I installed rvm and things got even worst, all things messed!

And so I started want to clean all things and use rvm again! I want to uninstall all gems, all rails, and all ruby versions, except the system's default one (the very old one born with the mac).

Or any other better solutions or suggestions!? Please help!

there is some info that I think will be useful:

```
which -a ruby

/opt/local/bin/ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

which -a rails

/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rails

which -a compass # simliar for rspec and many other gems

/usr/local/bin/compass
/usr/local/bin/compass

gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
actionpack (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activemodel (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2)
activerecord (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activeresource (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activesupport (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
addressable (2.2.2)
arel (2.0.6, 1.0.1, 1.0.0.rc1)
authlogic (2.1.6, 2.1.3)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)
base32 (0.1.2)
block_helpers (0.3.3)
bluecloth (2.0.9)
bowline (0.9.4)
bowline-bundler (0.0.4)
bson (1.1.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
compass (0.10.6)
crack (0.1.7)
devise (1.1.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
differ (0.1.1)
dynamic_form (1.1.3)
engineyard (1.3.1)
engineyard-serverside-adapter (1.3.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
escape (0.0.4)
extlib (0.9.15)
facebooker (1.0.75)
faker (0.3.1)
faraday (0.5.3, 0.5.2)
fast_gettext (0.5.10, 0.4.17)
fastercsv (1.5.3)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (0.6.3)
formatize (1.0.1)
formtastic (1.1.0, 1.0.1)
gemcutter (0.5.0)
gettext (2.1.0)
git (1.2.5)
gosu (0.7.25 universal-darwin)
haml (3.0.24, 3.0.23, 3.0.22, 3.0.21, 3.0.18)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
heroku (1.10.13, 1.9.13)
highline (1.5.2)
hirb (0.3.4, 0.3.3)
hpricot (0.8.2)
i18n (0.5.0, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.3.7)
jeweler (1.4.0)
json (1.4.6)
json_pure (1.4.3)
linkedin (0.1.8)
locale (2.0.5)
mail (2.2.12, 2.2.11, 2.2.10, 2.2.9, 2.2.7, 2.2.6.1)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
meta_search (0.9.8, 0.9.7.2, 0.9.7.1, 0.9.6, 0.9.4)
mime-types (1.16)
mongo (1.1.2)
mongoid (2.0.0.beta.20)
multi_json (0.0.5)
multipart-post (1.0.1)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.2.6, 0.2.4, 0.2.3)
net-ldap (0.1.1)
nice-ffi (0.4)
nokogiri (1.4.4, 1.4.2)
oa-basic (0.1.6)
oa-core (0.1.6)
oa-enterprise (0.1.6)
oa-oauth (0.1.6)
oa-openid (0.1.6)
oauth (0.4.4, 0.4.3, 0.4.1)
oauth-plugin (0.4.0.pre1)
oauth2 (0.1.0)
omniauth (0.1.6)
paperclip (2.3.6, 2.3.4, 2.3.1.1)
passenger (2.2.12)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.2)
querybuilder (0.9.2, 0.5.9)
rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rack-cache (0.5.3)
rack-cache-purge (0.0.2, 0.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-openid (1.2.0)
rack-test (0.5.6, 0.5.4)
railroady (0.11.2)
rails (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.9, 2.3.5, 2.3.4)
railties (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2)
rake (0.8.7)
RedCloth (3.0.4)
rest-client (1.6.1)
roxml (3.1.5)
rscribd (1.2.0)
rspec (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.3.0, 2.2.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-mysql (2.9.3)
ruby-ole (1.2.10.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
ruby-recaptcha (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
ruby-sdl-ffi (0.3)
ruby-termios (0.9.6)
ruby_parser (2.0.5)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygame (2.6.4)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
rubyless (0.7.0, 0.6.0, 0.3.5)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rubyzip2 (2.0.1)
scribd_fu (2.0.6)
searchlogic (2.4.27, 2.4.23)
sequel (3.16.0, 3.15.0, 3.13.0)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
shoulda (2.11.3)
sinatra (1.0)
slim (0.8.0)
slim-rails (0.1.2)
spreadsheet (0.6.4.1)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2, 1.3.1)
ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
subdomain-fu (1.0.0.beta2, 0.5.4)
supermodel (0.1.4)
syntax (1.0.0)
taps (0.3.13, 0.3.11)
templater (1.0.0)
temple (0.1.6)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.14.6, 0.14.4, 0.14.3, 0.14.1, 0.14.0)
tilt (1.1)
treetop (1.4.9, 1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
uuidtools (2.1.1, 2.0.0)
validates_timeliness (3.0.0.beta.4, 2.3.1)
warden (0.10.7)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2, 2.3.15, 2.3.14)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
ya2yaml (0.30)
yajl-ruby (0.7.8, 0.7.7)
yamltest (0.7.0)
zena (0.16.9, 0.16.8)
```

======

I have ran `sudo rvm implode` and `sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm`, so no rvm now.

```
gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/peter/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
```

===

```
ls -al /usr/local/lib/

total 5704
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel      238 Jun  1  2010 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel      306 Dec 15 16:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1717208 Jun  1  2010 libruby-static.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1191880 Jun  1  2010 libruby.1.8.7.dylib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel       19 Jun  1  2010 libruby.1.8.dylib -> libruby.1.8.7.dylib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel       19 Jun  1  2010 libruby.dylib -> libruby.1.8.7.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel      204 Jun  1  2010 ruby
```

Comment: Please add the output of `rvm info` and `gem env`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, um... you've been ... ah ... busy. Trying to clean things up will be a challenge and will probably be more than we can help with unless we can see into a lot of the system directories and your account's configuration.

My first question is: Have you made any changes to the system's default Ruby in /usr/bin/ruby? If so, I'd personally just back up the data I want to keep and wipe the drive and start over.

Have you run `gem clean`? That will remove a bunch of garbage, but will also probably raise a lot of questions about dependencies, and, when done, could leave things broken or unchanged - it's hard to say with that number of gems and revisions what will happen.

You can force gem to uninstall all the gems using something like:

```
gem list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs gem --all --quiet uninstall
```

Just be sure which Ruby version is running, because gem will act against the currently running Ruby. Use `which ruby` to find out.

Comment: I don't thing I have changed the system's ruby. I ran `gem clean` and removed a lot gems' old versions. But I want to remove all of them and then reinstall it again...

Comment: Am I safe to just sudo rm -rf all ruby except the one in /usr/bin/ruby?

Comment: Yes, if you do it VERY methodically and carefully. You could wipe your entire drive with that command too, which would be one of those "oh sh*t" moments.

Comment: Look through your `PATH` and clean it up too. Also make sure `/usr/local/bin` doesn't have softlinks or remnants of a Ruby you installed. You have to be painstaking to remove the left-overs, which is why I said it might be easier to wipe and reinstall.

Comment: the cmd for force uninstalling gave the following error: `ERROR:  Invalid option: --all.  See 'gem --help'.`

Comment: `--all` is supposed to tell gem to remove all the versions. You could remove it and run the command string a couple times, until nothing is returned by `gem list`. You might want to add `--ignore-dependencies`.

Comment: after removing --all, --quite caused error too. I removed --all and --quite and added sudo before gem uninstall and uninstalled the gems successfully! How do I know all gems in all ruby versions has been uninstalled? How to switch to another version of ruby??? (I wanted to give you 1m upvotes!)

Comment: To check all gems in all versions of Ruby you'll need to switch to each version of Ruby in turn, and run `gem list`. To switch to another version of Ruby adjust your PATH to have that Ruby's path first in the list.

Comment: Also check `/usr/local/share`, `/usr/local/lib`, ... for stray files; same goes for similar directories under `/opt`. Cinderella (https://github.com/atmos/cinderella) will help keep things clean after you have a fresh start.

Comment: @mu is too short, `/usr/local/share` seems contained nothing related to ruby, but there files in `/usr/local/lib`, I would post the files to my question.